# Filtering JSON array based on conditional value in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, filter, conditional-statements

Since month I am struggling to filter a huge JSON file. The data are presented as:

```
{
    'network': '2a0d:4bc0::/29',
    'metric': 100,
    'primary': true,
    'id':'2a0d: 4bc0::/29',
    'bgp':{
        'origin': 'IGP',
        'ext_communities': [],
        'large_communities': [
            [6695, 1000, 1],
            [6695, 1902, 9009]
        ],
        'med': 0,
        'as_path': [34549, 3214],
        'next_hop': '2001:7f8:a0::86f5:0:1fe80::42de:ad03:61d1:efe4',
        'communities':[
            [0, 6939],
            [0, 9009],
            [0, 32934],
            [0, 48793],
            [0, 57344],
            [3214, 200],
            [6695, 9145],
            [34549, 100],
            [34549, 300],
            [65212, 11000],
            [65101, 1001],
            [65102, 1000],
            [65103, 276],
            [65104, 150]
        ],
        'local_pref': 100
    }
}
```

```
>>> with gzip.open(file, 'rt') as f:
  ....data = json.load(f)
```

I am able to access data by coding as follow using the different keys:

```
>>> for i in data: 
   ...for element in data[i][exported]:
   .....print(element['bgp']['communities'], element['bgp']['large_communities'])
```

where I have the following output:

```
[
    [0, 12989],
    [0, 13335],
    [0, 15133],
    [0, 15169],
    [0, 16509],
    [0, 20940],
    [0, 22822],
    [0, 2906],
    [0, 32590],
    [0, 48641],
    [0, 49029],
    [0, 714],
    [65101, 11077],
    [65102, 11000],
    [65103, 724],
    [65104, 150]
]
```

What I want is to filter value which initiated by '0' for example `[0, 9009], [0, 48793]....` where the output could be look like:

```
[
    [0, 12989],
    [0, 13335],
    [0, 15133],
    [0, 15169],
    [0, 16509],
    [0, 20940],
    [0, 22822],
    [0, 2906],
    [0, 32590],
    [0, 48641],
    [0, 49029],
    [0, 714]
]
```

or those which begin by `65101`

I don't know which filter methods to use.

Thanks

Comment: it's difficult to read your code. modify your question to better see the code. It makes it easier to understand the question and also for the contributors to answer you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
# Load your data
data = None
with open(file, 'r') as file:
    data = json.loads(file.read())

# Load communities field, filter on values with 0 or 65101 in the first column
communities = data['bgp']['communities']
result = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 0 or x[0] == 65101, communities))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just changed the  json keys but it work fine.